# How do I get the final node embeddings in a GCN?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, transformer-model, graph-neural-network

I'm building a GCN on the UPFD (Fake News Detection) graph dataset. My code performs graph classification. I need to obtain the final node embeddings for further use in my project.

This is the code so far:

```
current_file = '.'

train_dataset = UPFD(current_file, 'politifact', 'spacy', 'train', ToUndirected())
val_dataset = UPFD(current_file, 'politifact', 'spacy', 'val', ToUndirected())
test_dataset = UPFD(current_file, 'politifact', 'spacy', 'test', ToUndirected())

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=128, shuffle=True)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=128, shuffle=False)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=128, shuffle=False)

# before_training = train_dataset[0].x
# print('Feature vector(node embedding) of datapoint #0 (before gtn):\n\t', train_dataset[0].x)


class GraphTransformer(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, hidden_channels, out_channels,
                 concat=False):
        super().__init__()
        self.concat = concat

        self.conv1 = GCNConv(in_channels, hidden_channels)
        self.conv2 = TransformerConv(hidden_channels, hidden_channels)
        self.conv3 = TransformerConv(hidden_channels, hidden_channels)

        if self.concat:
            self.lin0 = Linear(in_channels, hidden_channels)
            self.lin1 = Linear(2 * hidden_channels, hidden_channels)

        self.lin2 = Linear(hidden_channels, out_channels)

    def forward(self, x, edge_index, batch):
        h = self.conv1(x, edge_index).relu()
        h = self.conv2(h, edge_index).relu()
        h = self.conv3(h, edge_index).relu()
        h = global_max_pool(h, batch)

        if self.concat:
            # Get the root node (tweet) features of each graph:
            root = (batch[1:] - batch[:-1]).nonzero(as_tuple=False).view(-1)
            root = torch.cat([root.new_zeros(1), root + 1], dim=0)
            news = x[root]

            news = self.lin0(news).relu()
            h = self.lin1(torch.cat([news, h], dim=-1)).relu()

        h = self.lin2(h)
        return h.log_softmax(dim=-1)


device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = GraphTransformer(train_dataset.num_features, 128, train_dataset.num_classes, concat=True).to(device)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, weight_decay=0.01)
```

I tried printing the node embeddings after the model but it gave the same embeddings as before passing through the model. Is a duplicate copy made and modified by the library functions or is the original modified? What do I do? Is there any way to get the final node embeddings?